# iPhone: cellForRowAtIndexPath - how to call it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Assuming self.tableView is a UITableView instance variable that I created, can anyone explain the difference between these 2 statements? Both syntactically are correct, and I would think both would do the same thing: return a cell at self.tableView for that index path.

```
NSIndexPath myIndexPath = BLAH BLAH...

UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sends a `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` message to the table view's data source.

The second sends a `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` message to the table view itself. The table view will, in turn, ask the data source for the cell.

Comment: This of course assumes the correct references between the data source (`self`) and `self.tableView` are made.